# When I threshold an image I get a completely black image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

[image: Wave image]

I am attempting to threshold a wave so that the white background appears black and the wave itself which was originally black is white, however it only seems to return an entirely black image. What am I doing wrong?

```
import cv2 
src = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\ksatt\\Desktop\\SoundByte\\blackwaveblackaxis (1).PNG",0)

maxValue = 255
thresh= 53

if not src is None:
    th, dst = cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.imshow("blackwave.PNG", dst)
    cv2.imwrite("blackwave.PNG", dst)
    cv2.waitKey(0) 
else:
    print 'Image could not be read'
```

Comment: maybe each of the values is bigger than 53? Did you try a higher threshold like 100 or even 200 to find out whether the outpur changes (then provably to all-white)? You should give otsu threshold a chance to find a proper value.

Comment: BTW you can use `if src is not None` instead of `if not src is None` which is more readable and easier to debug (e.g. does `if not src is None` mean `if not (src is None)` or does it mean `if (not (src)) is None`)?

Answer (score 1):

Your threshold is too low, and the dark paper is going to pick up values that you don't want anyways. Basically, the contrast of the image is too low.

One easy solution is to subtract out the background. The simple way to do this is to [`dilate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) your grayscale image, which will expand the white area and overtake the black lines. Then you can apply a small [`GaussianBlur()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#cv2.GaussianBlur) to that dilated image, and this will give you a "background" image that you can subtract from your original image to get a clear view of the lines. From there you'll have a much better image to [`threshold()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cv2.threshold), and you can even use OTSU thresholding to automatically set the threshold level for you.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

# read image
src = cv2.imread('wave.png',0)
```

[image]

```
# create background image
bg = cv2.dilate(src, np.ones((5,5), dtype=np.uint8))
bg = cv2.GaussianBlur(bg, (5,5), 1)
```

[image: Background image]

```
# subtract out background from source
src_no_bg = 255 - cv2.absdiff(src, bg)
```

[image: Subtracted background]

```
# threshold
maxValue = 255
thresh = 240
retval, dst = cv2.threshold(src_no_bg, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

[image: Manual threshold]

```
# automatic / OTSU threshold
retval, dst = cv2.threshold(src_no_bg, 0, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image: OTSU thresholding]

You can see that manual thresholding gives the same results as OTSU, but you don't have to play around with the values for OTSU, it'll find them for you. This isn't always the best way to go but it can be quick sometimes. Check out [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) for more on different thresholding operations.

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold it will tell you what each parameter does of the function.

Also here is a good tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

> Python: cv.Threshold(src, dst, threshold, maxValue, thresholdType) →
>   None
>   Is the prototype which gets further explenation in the mentioned API.

So simply change your code to:

```
cv2.threshold(src,RESULT, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow("blackwave.PNG", RESULT)
```

Comment: This uses the deprecated `cv` namespace which is not what the OP is using.

Answer (score -1):

Could you post a picture of the wave? Have you tried using standard python? Something like this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

maxValue = 255
thresh= 53

A = np.load('file.png')
# For each pixel, see if it's above/below the threshold
for i in range(A.shape[0]):      # Loop along the X direction
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):   # Loop along the Y direction
        # Set to black the background
        if A[i,j] > thresh:
            A[i,j] = 0
        if A[i,j] == 0:
            A[i,j] = 255
```

Or something similar.

Comment: while this solution works, it does not tackle the ops original problem

Comment: There is no need to loop over every pixel (there hardly ever is with `numpy`). Simply `A>thresh = 0; A==0 = 255` would do, and would be substantially faster.